# How to deal with Adsense issue Not Authorized error

Tags: android, adsense

This is 11th of october night, i am facing issue with Google adsense app, it just keep saying Not Authorized and does not show any data.is this only me facing this issue or this is happening globally? Is there any possiblity google just silently shutting down adsense android app? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Google discontinues AdSense mobile apps, will focus on web app instead.

Basically go onto the adsense website on chrome in your mobile, under settings add that page to your "android home screen"

The current plan is for the native apps to be deprecated "in the coming months," with a full shutdown coming by the end of this year. It's not too suprising that the mobile apps are going away, considering neither has been updated in over a year — the last iOS update was in November 2017, and the last Android update was a month later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes..  getting Not authorized error for me also. 
Clear data, sign-in again and again, force close .. nothing working.. but Adsense Web interface loading on mobile Chrome without any issues. So this must be an issue with Google itself.